# Macbook Pro 2012 WiFi card not supported?

Tags: wifi, drivers, macbook

When I was installing elementary OS i could connect to WiFi. This was when I was using a USB flash drive to hold the elementary image. I booted into the USB drive, connected to my WiFi, then clicked "install". I chose `ext4` for my file system.

I am running on a base model Macbook Pro 2012 retina. Why is the WiFi not available after installing it in my laptop SSD? Also I opened terminal and typed `iwconfig`, I get "no wireless extensions".

Using latest version.

P.S. also posted on Reddit.

Comment: Please execute this command in your [tag:terminal] `lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network ` to identify your card. After that search for it's driver and install it.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a MacBook Pro, more than likely it's got a Broadcom wifi chip. These require a driver to work correctly under Linux. All you need to do is connect to the internet temporarily using either a USB WiFi adapter or Ethernet and then run `sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source`

I know certain Mac models can be a bit more problematic, but usually that one package does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

As [mr.k99](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users/16939/mr-k99) said, you need to install `bcmwl-kernel-source`

Here is how I did it on my MacBook Pro by chrooting from USB:

Boot from USB, where wireless driver is installed, then execute the following:

```
$ sudo mkdir /media/target
$ sudo mount /dev/sdaX /media/target
$ sudo mount --bind /dev /media/target/dev
$ sudo mount --bind /proc /media/target/proc
$ sudo mount --bind /sys /media/target/sys
$ sudo chroot /media/target
# apt install bcmwl-kernel-source
```